# Monitor Docker Container for No Output

Tags: bash, docker, shell-scripting, containers

I have a long running process in a docker container that is setup like this:

*Dockerfile*

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["./invoke.sh"]
```

*invoke.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
./long-running-command
```

If *long-running-command* is running properly, it will send output to STDERR every few seconds. If it hangs, it will stop outputting to STDERR. How can I use a monitor or parent process to auto-detect when *long-running-command* has stopped writing data for a period of time (about 2 minutes) and auto-kill *long-running-command*?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/):

> By default, docker logs or docker service logs shows the command’s output just as it would appear if you ran the command interactively in a terminal.

Use the `docker logs` command to check stderr.

To kill the command, you can stop the container. If that is not possible or desirable, there are [methods to find the PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878808/finding-docker-container-processes-from-host-point-of-view) of the long running process.

Comment: I am looking for an automated solution. I have clarified the question.